# Networking program only outputting 1's

Tags: java

Essentially i have made a program that sends text to another computer by encoding it into a form of binary that is 6 digits long to save space but that is not the point, how it sends the data is. It connects using a Socket. Then if it is a 0 it disconnects immediately, but if it is a 1 it waits a certain amount of time then closes the socket. Here is the code i am using to send the text:

*encoded is a Array List of Boolean

```
for(int i = 0;i < encoded.size();i+=6){
        for(int b = i; b < i+6; b++){
        Socket s1 = new Socket(ip,5576);
        if(encoded.get(b) == true){
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        s1.close();
        }

    }
```

and the server code is this:

```
while(true){
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        if(first){
            first = false;
            continue;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if(!s.isClosed()){
            encoded.add(true);
            zerosInRow = 0;
            System.out.println(1);
        }else{
            encoded.add(false);
            zerosInRow++;
            System.out.println(0);
        }
        if(zerosInRow >= 6){
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-1);
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-2);
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-3);
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-4);
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-5);
            encoded.remove(encoded.size()-6);
            break;
        }
    }
```

but the problem is it only outputs 1's when i run it

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: That is meant to be there so it can check if it is a 0 or a 1, because your ping will never be 0

Answer (score 0):

`Socket.isClosed()` tells you whether *you* have closed *this socket*.

It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection.

To determine whether the *peer* has closed the *connection* within a timeout, you need to *set* a read timeout and do a *read*. If you get a `SocketTimeoutException`, the connection is still open. If `read()` returns -1, it is closed.